# Como vaciar una lista si ya se asignaron los elementos ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, poo, java-ee, java-8

Presento la siguiente duda, después de asignar los valores correspondientes según el criterio. Como hago para vaciar la lista.

```
    public void depurar() {

    Contacto contact = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
        contact = contactos.get(i);
        if (contact.getDireccion() != null) {
            correctos.add(contact);
        }
        if (null == contact.getDireccion()) {
            incorrectos.add(contact);
        }
    }

    }
```

Al imprimir me brinda esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que se debe colocar algo así `contacto.remove(contact)`. Pero al realizar esto no funciona de manera correcta la condición como se evidencia a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En contactos debe salirme el valor de 0, ya que fueron asignadas pero hace falta vaciar esta lista de contactos.

Comment: si usas remove, en este caso debes usar el indice del elemento a eliminar: .remove(indice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es un `ArrayList` puedes vaciar toda la lista usando el mètodo `clear()` :

```
myArrayList.clear();
```

por ejemplo:

```
contactos.clear();
```

Si deseas eliminar un elemento puedes usar `remove()` definiendo el indice del elemento que deseas eliminar:

```
myArrayList.remove(0);
```

por ejemplo puedes crear un bucle para eliminar todos los elementos contenidos en el `ArrayList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
        contactos.remove(i);        
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la explicación me ha quedado mas claro respecto a `remove()` y `clear()`, andaba confundido pero es cuestión de prestar atencion, nuevamente agradezco tu colaboración. Ya me quedo claro como funciona los ArrayList. Codigo compilando,

Comment: Muy bien Kafira, que bueno que pude aclararte un poco màs, saludos.

Comment: No creo que sea buena idea remover elementos mientras se itera el arreglo, eso puede causar resultados inesperados.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar cuando termine el ciclo el metodo `clear()` para vaciar la lista.

```
for (int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
        contact = contactos.get(i);
        if (contact.getDireccion() != null) {
            correctos.add(contact);
        }
        if (null == contact.getDireccion()) {
            incorrectos.add(contact);
        }
    }
 contactos.clear();
```

Comment: Si correcto, el compañero anterior me dejo claro los términos. Igualmente agradezco tu contribución